# How to remove the first slash in my URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

i need to remove the first "/" in my url.
As you can see my first value is correct, now i need to do the same to the second url.
How can i delete the first "/"

```
option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=2     <    CORRECT
/option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=2     <   NOT GOOD FOR ME
```

Comment: Where is the URL coming from? In what context is this?

Comment: What is the context? Where is the URL? In a variable? Link?

Comment: 14 of your questions are eligible for one of the answers to be accepted.  You have currently accepted 0 answers.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for more information.

Comment: Is that really the correct url since it seems to be a / in a path and a querystring. Its possible that there is no query part and that what looks like that is actual the resource being pointed at but this seems unlikely...

Comment: I'm not sure if this question really has anything to do with jQuery -- is there a reason why it's called out in the title/tags?

Comment: @Zack Seems unnecessary yes. Given his past form, I doubt Davidino will get back to us to answer that question, or accept any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different way

`var rawurl = "/option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=2";`

`rawurl = rawurl.substr(rawurl.indexOf('/') + 1);`

Comment: +1 for not using regexp. We wouldn't want the OP to have *two* problems :)

Comment: @Zack Depends... OP didn't actually specify whether or not the first "/" is necessarily the first character

Comment: @Day... OP didn't really specify anything... :p

Comment: Well, if you're sure the slash is always there, this is OK, but this would be a silly question if the slash is always there

Comment: @Juan Mendes now I am sure I will always remove the first one :p

Comment: Except he didn't want to remove slashes that aren't in the beginning of the string? :P OP needs to clarify, I'm just playing devil's advocate. I would use `url.replace(/^\//, '')`

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
var str = "/option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=2";

str.replace(/\//, "");
```

Note: In this answer i have assumed you to save this part of url in variable str first.

Comment: Need to escape inside your regexp: `str.replace(/\//, "")`. (and I don't think the " < NOT GOOD FOR ME" is part of the URL ;)

Comment: @Day: yes correct and also @pekka edited the question later, before not good for me appeared as a part of url :)