# Remove / from pathname

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an application where the user can see at the top of the page the name of the current page he is on. I was able to extract the page name through the useLocation hook. But the problem is that the pathname comes with / and when I put it to show on the page the page name comes out, for example: My page: /mypage. What I wanted was that it was possible to just take it, like this: My page: my page.

Comment: Use regex to remove the forward slash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731966/regex-remove-all-special-characters-except-numbers. You can also use the URL API to more easily work with paths: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the first slash in my URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784806/how-to-remove-the-first-slash-in-my-url-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.slice`

```js
const string = '/mypage'
const newString = string.slice(1)
console.log(newString)
```